# bootstrap 3 columns not stacking on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have been searching for ages and couldn't get the code below to work. Everything works just fine except that columns don't stack on mobile size view. I tried adding col-xs-12 and other variations but just can't figure it out.

```
<div class="container-fluid offers"> 
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-md-6 website-package">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 featured-image">
            <img class="center-block img-responsive package-icon" src="assets/img/website.png">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 featured-image">
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
         </div>         
       </div>
     </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 website-package">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 featured-image">
            <img class="center-block img-responsive package-icon" src="assets/img/online-shop.png">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 featured-image">
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
           </div>         
         </div>
       </div>   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the css for the various classes although I doubt that has anything to do with it so just in case.

```
.website-package {
    background: #5FA1A8;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 30px;
}

.featured-image{
    background:transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: Hi, have you tried to add `col-xs-12 col-sm-12` in your column ? Or could you put in on JSfiddle ?

Comment: @BillyHalim I made a fiddle (my first time using it so please let me know if anything is missing). What is weird though is that the results window in JSfiddle shows the columns stacked.    [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3z1btenk/#&togetherjs=nCl4pAzRat)

Answer (score 0):

you probably made a mistake. I saw there is `margin:30px` on your `.website-package`. Delete that or use `margin:0px 30px`. This is the JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3z1btenk/1/

Comment: I tried both mentioned variations but it simply removed the spacing between the columns. On mobile there are still two columns being shown. For a live version please check dev.testing.homepage-labor.ch

Comment: Stacking is same as spacing removed between the columns

Comment: Oh maybe I used wrong terminology here since I am quite new to bootstrap, if so I apologize. I meant that on mobile, each element should be under the previous one, effectively spanning the whole screen width.

Comment: Yes, you have done that previously. When you on mobile device size, the next element will be under the previous element

Comment: I must be missing something, sorry for my newbiness ;) I had removed the margin as you said but the site is still showing both columns next to each other. I emptied cache on my phone and visited the previously mentioned link to make sure. What am I missing here?

Comment: There are 4 ways to manage your grid system size in Bootstrap : `xs` for smallest screen devices, `sm` for small devices, `md` for medium devices, `lg` for large devices. I think you should refee to the bootstrap grid system documentation here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/. Scroll until you find Grid System

Comment: I already tried all variations (to my knowledge) to define the columns for xs etc. It worked at first until I started nesting the columns inside for the image/icon with the omg-responsive class in order to give it an appropriate size.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: First I had everything (image and text) inside the <div class="col-md-6 website-package"> but the image showed to big so I nested another row inside which made it not stack anymore.

Comment: Just change the image size

Comment: Hey it worked. I should have thought about but was blind in rage I guess ;) thank you so much :)